# How to clean tab-delimited file with pages

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a tab-delimited file that looks similar to this:

```
01/17/2017 Display Warehouse Stocks of Material                                       1

Material            Plnt    SLoc    SL  BUn       Unrestricted     Transit/Transf.    In Quality Insp.      Restricted-Use             Blocked             Returns

1111            5252    7000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
2222            4646    7000        EA             30.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000

1/17/2017 Display Warehouse Stocks of Material                                       2

Material            Plnt    SLoc    SL  BUn       Unrestricted     Transit/Transf.    In Quality Insp.      Restricted-Use             Blocked             Returns

3333            6060    6000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
4444            5252    6000        EA             10.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
```

As you can see this file have pages after a certain amount of data
I need clean the data to have something similar to this:

```
Material            Plnt    SLoc    SL  BUn       Unrestricted     Transit/Transf.    In Quality Insp.      Restricted-Use             Blocked             Returns
1111            5252    7000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
2222            4646    7000        EA             30.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
3333            6060    6000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
4444            5252    6000        EA             10.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
```

I made a script with python partially cleans the file.

```
def _cleanup(txtfile):
  file = open(txtfile, 'r+')
  lines = file.readlines()
  file.seek(0)
  for line in lines:
    if line.startswith((' ', '\tMaterial')) == False and line.startswith((' ', '\t')):
      file.write(line)
  file.truncate()
  file.close()
  return True


def _main():
  sample = 'sample.txt'
  print('Done' if _cleanup(sample) else 'Something is wrong')


_main()
```

And the script give me this:

```
1111            5252    7000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
2222            4646    7000        EA             30.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
3333            6060    6000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
4444            5252    6000        EA             10.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
```

As you can see the script remove the table headers, something that I need.

I know that may be is not the best option to do this, if you know another way is welcome!

The principal objective of this is put the data in a database table, may be I'm in the incorrect way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you are missing header. In this case just add the first occurance of header line to output file

```
def _cleanup(txtfile):
  file = open(txtfile, 'r+')
  lines = file.readlines()
  file.seek(0)
  AddHeader=False
  for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(('\tMaterial'))==True  and AddHeader==False:
        file.write(line)
        AddHeader=True
    if line.startswith((' ', '\tMaterial')) == False and line.startswith((' ', '\t')):
      file.write(line)
  file.truncate()
  file.close()
  return True


def _main():
  sample = 'sample.txt'
  print('Done' if _cleanup(sample) else 'Something is wrong')


_main()
```

output

```
Material            Plnt    SLoc    SL  BUn       Unrestricted     Transit/Transf.    In Quality Insp.      Restricted-Use             Blocked             Returns
1111            5252    7000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
2222            4646    7000        EA             30.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
3333            6060    6000        EA             20.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
4444            5252    6000        EA             10.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000               0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions...with a key "^[0-9]{4}.*"  --without quotes.

^ - start of line
[0-9] - any number
{4}  - repeated 4 times
.* - get the whole line

That should do it.

Below is a link on how to read from a file with regular expressions.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40423/reading-from-text-file-with-regexmatch

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, if the line is non-empty and its first item is an integer then you want it; otherwise, not. Then this code should do what you want.

```
>>> headerFound = False
>>> with open('sample.txt') as sample:
...     for line in sample.readlines():
...         line = line.strip()
...         if line:
...             items = line.split()
...             if items[0]=='Material' and not headerFound:
...                 print (items)
...                 headerFound = True
...                 continue
...             try:
...                 first = int(items[0])
...                 print (items)
...             except:
...                 pass
...             
['Material', 'Plnt', 'SLoc', 'SL', 'BUn', 'Unrestricted', 'Transit/Transf.', 'In', 'Quality', 'Insp.', 'Restricted-Use', 'Blocked', 'Returns']
['1111', '5252', '7000', 'EA', '20.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
['2222', '4646', '7000', 'EA', '30.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
['3333', '6060', '6000', 'EA', '20.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
['4444', '5252', '6000', 'EA', '10.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
```

Fancier versions are, of course, possible. You could check for the appearance of a slash to eliminate lines. You could check for alphabetic characters.

Comment: Great! I like this way but is missing the row "BUn" that not have data but is necessary consider, like a None or white space.

Comment: Missed that! But easy to correct. See edited answer.